# Android OBD distance travelled command giving NO DATA

Tags: android, bluetooth, obd-ii

I have connected my android application with bluetooth OBD device. Now, on running commands like vehicle speed,rpm,ambient air temperature,I m getting the desired and right  response but when I hit the distance command(0131\r) ,I am again getting the response NO DATA.
Please help me in solving this.

Comment: Anyone who knows the answer?

Comment: Is it solved? u still need help? According to Data Sheet No Data is obtained when -The IC waited for the period of time that was set by AT ST, and detected no response from the vehicle. It may be that the vehicle had no data to offer for that particular PID, that the mode requested was not supported.

Comment: Thanks,It is solved now.It occurs because the mode requested was not supported on the vehicle.You are right.

Comment: So, How to know the mode request is supported or not ?
What kind of car is support that distance travelled mode?

Comment: Hi @Devil for me, my application not working some cars , like getting error like  "Error running 01 46, response: NODATA" Do you have any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately according to the SAE J1979 spec, vendor support for pretty much every single PID is optional. Commands, such as `0100\r\n` give you an indication of which PIDs are *theoretically* supported by your vehicle, but whether an ECU will respond or not is completely vendor and vehicle dependent (and sometimes also depending on temporary/environmental conditions).

Comment: Hi @DrMickeyLauer,  my application not working some cars , like getting error like "Error running 01 46, response: NODATA" Do you have any idea ?